# Bazel build using different compiler

Tags: tensorflow, distributed-system, bazel

How can I specify the compiler for Bazel to use? I see the `--compiler` option [here](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/bazel-user-manual.html#build), but no explanation of its use.

I have read about making [new toolchains](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/wiki/Building-with-a-custom-toolchain), but it appears that it is per project or something. For Tensorflow in particular, I want to use a [icecc](https://github.com/icecc/icecream) install I have on my machines so I can distribute the build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a wrapper around gcc, doing `export CC=/path/to/icecc` should just work and start using icecc with bazel 0.4.5. If icecc requires special environment variable you might have to add [`--action_env` flags](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/command-line-reference.html#flag--action_env).

Note that Bazel was created to run with the Google compilation cluster and as a consequence separate each compilation action, that might interact badly with icecc assumptions.